# How to deal with Elasticsearch's lack of atomic transactions?

Tags: elasticsearch, transactions, microservices

We are using an Elasticsearch databases to create projections and materialized views from our "write" databases, to serve end users use cases without relying on heavy SQL queries all the time.

To do that, we need a projector application to keep those elasticsearch indexes up-to-date. Our "write" db application owner will produce messages to our message broker about everything that happens in the database, so our projectors can update our "read" models in elasticsearch and we have our "read" models always eventually updated.

Now imagine an event is consumed by a projector and it needs to update a piece of information in 3 different indexes. Those 3 different indexes serves different use cases, but need the updated data.

As Elasticsearch isn't an ACID database and does not support atomic transactions, what strategies should we use to guarantee consistency when updating multiple indexes that are related to the updated data? What should we do if the first index is updated correctly by the projector but the second fails for any reason? How should we handle this inconsistency?

We've thought in some options like implementing some sort of SAGA, reverting the first successful updates if one fails after; some sort of retry or circuit breaker mechanism assuming the fail is transient, and some other. I personally don't like none of them for different reasons, but I'm open to discuss about it here.

Comment: Before diving into any other options, is there any chance to change the data model to only need a single copy of the data? That would make it so much easier...

Comment: @xeraa the problem is that we are using different schemas (ie. different ES indexes) for different use cases. So, to group all the different use cases data into a single schema would increase network load and processing time for every use case dependent on this data. It is a possibility indeed, but isn't elasticsearch meant to be used as I described we are using in the first place?

Comment: You mean because the combined entity would be larger? I don't know the exact tradeoffs here but that would be something I'd try out to save a lot of other pain. And multi-document transactions were never a feature of Elasticsearch — you'd always need to build some workarounds.

Comment: @xeraa thank you for the insightful answer. So just to confirm, the way we are supposed to use elasticsearch as a projected database is to have 1 single index/schema to support all use cases? Let's say we have an index dedicated to store users data. As different use cases that would demand joins or querying multiple indexes, we should just append those use cases inside the same index/schema? It's an interesting approach as it completely resolves the lack of synchronization we are facing. I'll take that into account, thanks again!

Comment: We always like to say "it depends" . Maybe you could also do independent writes and handle in your application the very off chance that a write fails (not responding with a 200 or 201)? IMO there are multiple ways to solve this but transactions aren't a thing on the way there.